# Can you find the name of the account that joined a computer to Azure AD?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

```
Get-AzureADAuditDirectoryLogs -Filter "activityDisplayName eq 'Register device' " | where-object Category -eq "Device"
```

And it brings back this

```
ActivityDateTime.DateTime
InitiatedBy.User.UserPrincipalName
```

My question is the InitiatedBy.User.UserPrincipleName i do not think is the account that actually - joined the device to the domain?

can someone confirm that this value is the account that actually did the domain join? or just the user of the registered device?

If it is the just the user - is there another way to find the actual user account that joined the device to the domain??

Answer (score 1):

Please ***check*** whether you enabled **`Device settings`** in **Portal** like below:

[image]

If that's the case, user can register and join the device to Azure AD. Then user of the **registered device** and user who **joined device** will be same.

I joined the device to Azure AD by **`signing in as user`** by selecting below option:

[image]

After joining to **Azure AD**, it displayed like below:

[image]

So, when I ran the below command, it displayed **`registered user`** details as **both are same**.

```
Get-AzureADAuditDirectoryLogs -Filter "activityDisplayName eq 'Register device' " | where-object Category -eq "Device"
```

**Response:**

[image]

**Alternatively**, you can run the below command where the user account that registered the device will become **`owner`** of it by ***default***.

```
Get-AzureADDeviceRegisteredOwner -ObjectId Device_ObjectID
```

**Response:**

[image]